# How can two left joins from a single table on similar fields be translated into LINQ when more than two tables are involved?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

This is the query:

```
SELECT colA, colB, colC
FROM TableA 
LEFT JOIN TableB 
ON TableA.colA = tablea.colA
LEFT JOIN TableC 
ON TableA.colA = TableC.colA
```

This is my LINQ code:

```
from a in TableA
join b in TableB on a.colA equals b.colA 
join c in TableC on a.colA equals c.colA 
select new { values here}
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cy08U.png) is the exact schema we will be using

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LEFT OUTER JOIN in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq)

Comment: [Don’t use Linq’s Join. Navigate!](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
data= (from a in TableA
join b in TableB on a.colA equals b.colA into bj
 from b in bj.DefaultIfEmpty()
join c in TableC on a.colA equals c.colA  into cj
 from c in cj.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { a.Cola,b.Colb, c.Colc}).ToList();
```